# Using ipython engine in knitr

Tags: python, r, ipython, knitr

I am trying to use ipython using knitr using the [knitron](https://github.com/fhirschmann/knitron) package. I have python, IPython, knitron installed on a windows machine.

However, executing this line does not find the ipython engine.

`{r engine='ipython'}`

and I get the following error, "Error in in_dir(opts_knit$get("root.dir") %n% input_dir(), (knit_engines$get(options$engine))(options)) : 
  attempt to apply non-function
Calls:  ... process_group.block -> call_block -> block_exec -> in_dir

Has anybody got this working?

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to load knitron using

```
library(knitron)
```

before executing

```
knit("doc.Rmd")
```

in order to register the engine? Knitron is not officialy part of knitr, it just registers as engine when being loaded.

Please also use the most recent version of knitron from GitHub.

Comment: I use RStudio for knitting but I realized that it works by explicitly using knit on the console. Also now I get an error, "Error in knitron.start(profile) : 
  IPython cluster could not be started. Giving up" but I did start it using "ipcluster start --profile=knitr --n=1"